# Why do I need to add Material Theme dependency in order to resolve DocumentFile

Tags: java, android

I needed to access the **DocumentFile**  class in my Android Studio project. I had a hell of a time getting it to resolve.

The Andriod Developers Documentation said that I needed to import **"androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile"**, but when I added the import, I was told that it couldn't resolve that import. It didn't like the '.documentfile.' portion.

After much hair pulling and gnashing of teeth, I stumbled on to the fact that I needed to add an implementation dependency on  **"com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"**. Once I added that to my build file, the include resolved and I had access to the DocumentFile class.

Why is this? Where is the documentation that states I needed to do this? Or, should I have done something different to get DocumentFile to resolve?

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I stumbled on to the fact that I needed to add an implementation dependency on "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0".

A dependency is required. However, that one overkill.

> Why is this?

You really need [the `androidx.documentfile:documentfile` dependency](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/documentfile/documentfile/). Apparently (and inexplicably) `com.google.android.material:material` pulls in `androidx.documentfile:documentfile` as a transitive dependency.

> Where is the documentation that states I needed to do this?

Generally, that sort of thing is not documented. That is one of the reasons I created [the AndroidX Tech site](https://androidx.tech). For example, to confirm the dependency for `DocumentFile`, I visited that site, clicked on "Classes > D*" in the nav bar, found `DocumentFile` in the list, and proceeded from there to get the artifact information.

Comment: Here is the original source for the required import.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/documentfile